# CSS: Not in correct position after adding position: fixed;

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

[image: Correct]

The div currently on the right is at the correct position, where i want it to be. But if the page gets too long, i want it to scroll along, so i add `position: fixed;`

[image: Incorrect]

But now its somewhere completely different. How can i fix this?

[JSfiddle with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/cLert/1/)

Comment: You've accidentally pasted your CSS into the JavaScript panel.

Comment: @thirtydot Oops! Edited. *shame*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed; 
    margin-left:620px;
}
```

I add 620px because your left column has 600px and before your `position: fixed` there were a 20px of margin between each columns.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `fixed` behaves like `absolute` (except that it will stay put when you scroll the page). You have to provide `top` and `left` values.

Try this:

```
#right {
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed; 
    left:710px;
}
```

Comment: Do i realy have to? Won't that become very unreliable? And how do i even do that?

Comment: Or right and bottom perhaps. position:fixed; top:40px; right:0px;